# background-image: url() not showing up

Tags: html, css, background-image

I'm familiar with html/css, but while experimenting with `background-image:url()`, nothing shows up. My html is very basic to test this out; my image path name is correct. I've exhausted all my resources and nothing is working.
Here is my html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="test.css"/>
    </head>
        <body>
            <img class="pic">
        </body>
</html>
```

CSS:

```
.pic {
    background-image: url(/Users/leslienguyen/Desktop/bgBullet4.png);
    background-size: cover;
}
```

I've already tried using `(-webkit-)background-size`, `background-attachment`, and checked if the files are all in the same location. The background sometimes works when I put `height` specific px but never works with `auto` either. I'm super stuck.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You must have a width height for your pic. I used a random image below for the purposes of running the code.

```css
    .pic {
        width:100%;
        height:100vh;
        background-image: url('https://image.shutterstock.com/image-photo/white-transparent-leaf-on-mirror-260nw-1029171697.jpg');
       background-size: cover;
    }
```

```html
<html>
    <head>
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="test.css"/>
    </head>
        <body>
            <img class="pic">
        </body>
</html>
```

Comment: This works! However, when I put the width as 100% and height: auto, it doesn't show up anymore. How can I go about fixing this?

Comment: I updated the answer, try setting width to 100% and height to 100vh maybe that will get you the correct result you are looking for.

Comment: Omg yes! I've been stuck for two days and this is the solution I've been looking for. Thank you so much!! :)

Comment: Glad I could be of assistance!

Answer (score 0):

you are trying to add a background image to an image tag `<img />` ! this is not how the img tag works

You can insert an image by using the `src` attribute

```html
<img src='/Users/leslienguyen/Desktop/bgBullet4.png' />
```

Or set the background to your `body` by simply moving the `class='pic'` to the body tag

```html
<body class='pic'>
</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to add ''  '' before and after your url adress.

Answer (score -2):

Try inserting your PNG File into Imgur, and then embedding the imgur link into the code, so do

```html
.pic {
    background-image: url((IMGUR URL.png);
    background-size: cover;
}
```

Comment: If above doesn't work try doing 

<img src="IMGURURL.png"class="pic"

Replace Imgururl with your embedded url.